# how fix problem [org.ovirt.vdsm.jsonrpc.client.reactors.ReactorClient] (SSL Stomp Reactor) [] Connecting to ovirt

Tags: ssl, virtual-machine, kvm, pki, ovirt

please tell me how I can solve this problem?
after an unexpected server reboot with Ovirt, the host and the storage domains were disconnected, the cluster does not rise.
I see such errors in the logs /var/log/ovirt-engine/engine.log:
2023-09-05 20:13:02,990+06 INFO [org.ovirt.vdsm.jsonrpc.client.reactors.ReactorClient] (SSL Stomp Reactor) [] Connecting to ovirt
2023-09-05 20:13:02,995+06 ERROR [org.ovirt.vdsm.jsonrpc.client.reactors.Reactor] (SSL Stomp Reactor) [] Unable to process messages General SSLEngine problem
2023-09-05 20:13:03,176+06 INFO [org.ovirt.vdsm.jsonrpc.client.reactors.ReactorClient] (SSL Stomp Reactor) [] Connecting to ovirt
2023-09-05 20:13:03,180+06 ERROR [org.ovirt.vdsm.jsonrpc.client.reactors.Reactor] (SSL Stomp Reactor) [] Unable to process messages General SSLEngine problem
2023-09-05 20:13:03,182+06 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.dal.dbbroker.auditloghandling.AuditLogDirector] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-engineScheduled-Thread-5) [] EVENT_ID: VDS_BROKER_COMMAND_FAILURE(10,802), VDSM command Get Host Capabilities failed: General SSLEngine problem
2023-09-05 20:13:03,182+06 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.monitoring.HostMonitoring] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-engineScheduled-Thread-5) [] Unable to RefreshCapabilities: VDSNetworkException: VDSGenericException: VDSNetworkException: General SSLEngine problem
looks like ssl certificates have flown, personal assumptions. but I'm not sure, so I would like a competent opinion from those who have experience with Ovirt.
I've never encountered Ovirt before, unfortunately, I've only worked with VMware ESXI, so I don't know many more nuances yet.

vdsm-client is working

Comment: i also checked wdsmd status and found the following error: Sep 06 02:41:14 ovirt-ekrm.office vdsm[69666]: ERROR ssl handshake: SSLError, address: ::ffff: